# Python pandas data frame reshape

Tags: python, pandas

The data shown below is an simplified example. The actual data frame is 3750 rows 2 columns data frame. I need to reshape the data frame into another structure.

```
A     A2
0.1   1
0.4   2
0.6   3
B     B2
0.8   1
0.7   2
0.9   3
C     C2
0.3   1
0.6   2
0.8   3
```

How can I reshape above data frame into horizontal as following:

```
A    A2    B    B2    C    C2
0.1  1     0.8  1     0.3  1
0.4  2     0.7  2     0.6  2
0.6  3     0.9  3     0.8  3
```

Comment: Please clarify whether the input is a raw text file or any python object. Also have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape your data and create a new dataframe:

```
cols = 6
rows = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T.reshape(cols,rows).T)
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(0)

    A    B    C  A2 B2 C2
1  0.1  0.8  0.3  1  1  1
2  0.4  0.7  0.6  2  2  2
3  0.6  0.9  0.8  3  3  3
```

Comment: Good one +1 , whats that `reshape(3,4)`

Comment: @pygo - here 3,4 represents rows, columns counts respectively.

Comment: Well @Gong you've changed the input data, this answer was to solve the problem with the input data you provided

Comment: Okay @Gong now it works for the more generic case of multiple input columns. You have to specify the dimensions of the resulting df using `rows` and `cols`

Answer (score 0):

try this, If you don't want to hard code your values.

```
df['header']=pd.to_numeric(df[0],errors='coerce')
l= df['header'].values
m_l = l.reshape((np.isnan(l).sum(),-1))[:,1:]
h=df[df['header'].isnull()][0].values
print pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(h,m_l)))
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  0.1  0.8  0.3
1  0.4  0.7  0.6
2  0.6  0.9  0.8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question. The data I typed in the question was a simplified example. And if there are 2 columns of data, and I want to reshape the data frame, is there a better way?